How would you write $ e^{i \frac{\pi}{4} \text{CNOT}}$ in ZX calculus?
How would you write $ e^{i \frac{\pi}{4} \text{CNOT}}$ operation in ZX calculus? Is there any simple method to write gates of the form $e^{i \frac{\pi}{4} \sigma_z^{(1)} \sigma_x^{(2)}}
$?


Is there any simple method to write gates of the form $e^{i \frac{\pi}{4} \sigma_z^{(1)} \sigma_x^{(2)}}
$?

This graph should perform $\exp(i \theta \cdot (Z \otimes X))$:

There may be a factor of 2 or division by 2 missing on $\theta$. The general idea is to make a graph that would measure the operator you want to phase, and make it phase instead of measure by attaching an angled leaf to its central node.

How would you write $ e^{i \frac{\pi}{4} \text{CNOT}}$ operation in ZX calculus?

Isn't that a different operation? CNOT's -1 eigenspace isn't degenerate whereas $X \otimes Z$ has a degenerate -1 eigenspace. In any case, you can decompose it into a series of three Pauli product rotations implemented as above. CNOT = $\sqrt{X_t \otimes Z_c} \cdot \sqrt{Z_c}^{-1} \cdot \sqrt{X_t}^{-1}$

Yes, those two are different operations, but the decomposition of the $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4} \sigma_x\cross \sigma_y} into single qubit gates and CNOT gate has a CNOT gate. So I was just trying to verify the decomposition using ZX calculus.... It would be really helpful if can elaborate What the General procedure is when writing graphs performing operations which are exponentials of tensor products?

@HypnoticZebra ZX can do arbitrary matrices, so you could look up papers on how they do that. But for unitary gates if you just decompose into a series of pauli product terms and apply this construction that will work.
